# Para que serve o "!mportant" no CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Varias vezes tenho visto esse **atributo** ou **propriedade** (nao sei exatamente como classifica-lo), mas continuo nao percebendo :

- Qual a necessidade de usa-lo ;
- Para que server extamente ;
- Quando usa-lo.

```css
h4, .texto{
  
      color:white !important;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serve para sobrepor o css ja atribuido para o elemento, Exemplo:

```css
.corAzul{
background-color: blue !important; 
}

.corVerde{
background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="background-color:red;" class="corAzul"/>
<input type="text" style="background-color:red;" class="corVerde"/>
```

Como pode ver no exemplo eu tenho as classes corAzul e corVerde sendo a azul como important e a verde não e inline eu coloquei para ser vemelho, No input1 ele traz azul e no verde ele considera o inline,
Então como tem os dois styles iguais para o mesmo elemento com o **!important** você diz ao browser qual ele deve considerar.